# Preventing LaTeX from replacing a variable

Tags: macros

I'm currently messing around with macros (rather new) and I seem to be missing something rather basic about LaTeX/TeX macros:

```
\def\car{Yes}
    \def\iszero#1{
    \ifnum#1=0{
        \let \car = Yes
    }
    \else{
        \let \car = No
    }
    \car
}
\iszero{1}
```

Returns Yes.

I was wondering why this happens and how I can prevent LaTeX from prematurely replacing `\car` with it's current value.

Comment: (1) You have a `\fi` missing (look at the output from when you run tex). (2) If you're using solely LaTeX (and not plain TeX), they say not to use `\def` (3) You can use `\tracingmacros=1` and look in the log file, to see what's going on (4) You can also use `\message` or `\show` I guess. (5) Also `\tracingassigns=1` which comes from eTeX (6) Something like `\let\car=No` will only eat up the `N` and leave `o` to appear in the output. (7) Assignments are reset when you exit the group. You can use `\global\let` to override this. (8) I'm not an expert so someone else will answer hopefully :-)

Comment: \let\car = No will 'define' car to correspond to the single character token 'N'  and leaves 'o' in the input stream, being displayed  then (assuming application of `\ifzero` in LaTeX's document body). You can't assign a bunch of tokens with let unless it is a control sequence token

Answer (score 7):

You want

```
\def\car{Yes}
\def\iszero#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0 % Terminate number with a space
    \def\car{Yes}%
  \else
    \def\car{No}%
  \fi
}
\iszero{1}
```

You are using a TeX primitive conditional, so the two branches are *not* places in braces: instead the are delimited by the end of the conditional, the `\else` and the `\fi`. The `\let` primitive can only be used to assigned one token to the value of a second one: you can't use it to define a macro, which needs `\def`.

Comment: The final `\car` is missing in the above (so the above prints nothing). Also, perhaps the OP was thinking of something like the following: one could also have `\def\yes{Yes}` and `\def\no{No}`, and then inside the `\if` use `\let\car=\yes` or `\let\car=\no` respectively.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I considered `\yes` and `\no` but without the wider context it's hard to be sure what is best; much the same with the find `\car`, which I suspect may be for diagnostics (otherwise why no just print the text in the conditional).

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for TeX conditionals does not use braces for the true and false branches.

Also `\let` behaves differently from what you seem to think: `\let\foo=<token>` makes `\foo` (almost) equivalent to `<token>`. In the case of

```
\let\car = Yes
```

the token `Y` would be assigned to `\car` and `es` would be printed (if in the nonskipped branch); same for `\let\car = No`.

You should use `\def`, instead. But there are better ways that don't require having `\car`.

Assuming plain TeX,

```
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\def\iszero#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
  {Yes}{No}%
}
```

would work: the `\expandafter` trick sweeps away the remnants of the conditional text, leaving either `\firstoftwo{Yes}{No}` or `\secondoftwo{Yes}{No}` in the input stream.

This can be generalized

```
\def\IfIsZeroTF#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
}
```

to be called like

```
\IfIsZeroTF{1}{Yes}{No}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively put the comparison inside the definition of `\car`.

```
%\def\car{Yes}%% Not needed for this example
\def\iszero#1{%
  \edef\car{%
    \ifnum#1=0
      Yes%
    \else
      No%
    \fi
  }}

False: \iszero{1}\car

True: \iszero{0}\car
```

I use `\edef` to get only `Yes` or`No` in `\car`. If `\def` is used there is a risk that the input is changed before evaluated, e.g. if the input is a counter.